# Extremely strange EAGLContext framebuffer initialization for SCNRenderer

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, scenekit, glkit

I have encountered extremely strange situation that has confused me this whole night. Basically what I want to do is to render SCNScene off-screen (without using [SCNView snapshot]). I have come across several stackoverflow questions without any answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589151/render-off-screen-scnscene-into-uiimage).

After spending a few hours playing around, I find it's the issue with EAGLContext initialization. This is what I copied from Apple:

```
_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
int width = 640;
int height = 480;

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext: _context];

glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
}
```

And render it with

SCNScene *scnScene = [SCNScene scene];

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
[scnScene.rootNode addChildNode: _node];
SCNRenderer *scnRender = [SCNRenderer rendererWithContext:_context options:nil];
scnRender.scene = scnScene;
SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
SCNCamera *mycamera = [SCNCamera camera];
cameraNode.camera = mycamera;
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);

GLKMatrix4 mat = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-1, 1,
                                     -5, 5,
                                     0.01, 100); // z range arbitrary
[cameraNode.camera setProjectionTransform:SCNMatrix4FromGLKMatrix4(mat)];
scnRender.pointOfView = cameraNode;
scnRender.delegate = self;
[scnRender render];
```

_node contains the model should be rendered.

With these code it renders empty scene (transparent UIImage).

However, if I initialize EAGLContext in a hacky way like this:

```
_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
_glkView = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
_glkView.context = _context;
[_glkView display];
```

_glkView doesn't even need to be added to ViewController's view or draw anything and [_glkView display] is need because that's when GLKView actually initialize its EAGLContext's frameBuffer and renderBuffer.

With this new _context initialized by GLKView, SCNRenderer works as expected.

I am really confused why the manually initialized renderBuffer, frameBuffer doesn't work with SCNRenderer, and why it works when initialized with GLKView.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/egoist-sx/d03a72d420f3646608fc) here for complete functions.