# can't take textureFromNode in SCNView overlay

Tags: ios, scenekit

In SceneKit we use overlay to draw a SpriteKit nodes

```
﻿///setup overlays
scnView.overlaySKScene = [[AAPLOverlayScene alloc] initWithSize:scnView.bounds.size];
```

Now I want to draw-and-snapshot some sknodes tree to sktexture:

```
﻿SKNode *tmp=[[SKNode alloc] init];
//draw some images on tmp
//....
SKTexture *tmpT = [self.view textureFromNode:tmp]; //crash
```

In logs: ﻿*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SCNView textureFromNode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12e5265a0'

As I see, it says "SCNView", not spritekit. So, **how to take texture from node in this case?**

**UPD** yes, I know about [screenshot of scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503472/cannot-create-a-screenshot-of-a-scnview). It is overhead, I need only sknode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a SCNView doesn't have this functionality (it doesn't implement "textureFromNode").
Maybe you can try to instantiate a SKView to perform the snapshot of the SKNode.

```
SKView *snapshotView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
SKTexture *tmpT = [snapshotView textureFromNode:tmp];
```

Comment: it works, but unfortunately, crashs after some iterations, sometimes at 2-nd and 3-rd time. Spent a hour to find dependencies, but nothing. Commenting from "SKTexture *tmpT=...." code solves crashes.

Comment: when and where do you execute this code? It might be a thread safety issue.