# How to take snapshot of the SCNView?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

SceneKit provides a method `snapshot()` for rendering view's scene into image object. But whenever I used this method the result comes `"<uninitialized>"`. I even tried to get image from current image context; App crashes logging as `SceneKit: error, Failed to bind EAGLDrawable: <CAEAGLLayer: 0x17422c380> to GL_RENDERBUFFER`

Comment: SCNView is chlid class of UIView so that you can use the category of UIView given below.

Comment: That question/ answer for OS X not iOS

Comment: No the link that @Anilsolanki commented was for OS X. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503472/cannot-create-a-screenshot-of-a-scnview this is the link.

Comment: My code is simple `mySCNView.snapshot()` this method does not render any thing or comes "<uninitialized>" in iOS 8 device.